# BitTorrent for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, p2p

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, and was wondering if there is a way to use a P2P file sharing program like Bit Torrent?

I have tried Transmission with no luck, and then installed qBittorrent again with no results.

The torrent does not seem to move and I get the following:

```
udp://open.demonii.com:1337   Not Working
udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969   Not Working
udp://zer0day.ch:1337   Not Working
udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969   Not Working
udp://exodus.desync.com:6969   Not Working
```

[image: Error]

Any troubleshooting help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu already comes with Transmission. See https://transmissionbt.com/.

Comment: Please clarify what you actually mean by "with no luck" and "no results".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to use Transmission:

1. Click the Ubuntu icon in the upper left corner of the screen
2. Type "Transmission" (something like "torrent" would work as well)
3. Click the "Transmission BitTorrent Client" icon

[image: Transmission BitTorrent Client in dash]

Comment: Ok I am doing that with a torrent right now but it doesn't appear to be downloading. It's been about 5 minutes.

Comment: @zzgooloo might be an issue with the torrent itself. How many seeders are on it? I would try a different torrent this doesn't appear to be Ubuntu related

Comment: I tried a few other torrents and none of them seem to start downloading. It reads Downloading metadata from 0 peers (0% done) There are many seeders for this over 2000. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Does [this Ubuntu torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent) work?

Comment: No I waited about 5 minutes to make sure and same result. Any ideas? Maybe some setting options need to be tweaked?

Comment: Your Internet provider might have a firewall that blocks BitTorrent in particular, whitelists only certain ports (BitTorrent tends to use high port numbers), or blocks UDP. You can try another BitTorrent client like Deluge (`sudo apt install deluge`) to see if that works. If both fail, your Internet provider is probably blocking BitTorrent in some way.

Comment: Thanks @ChaiT.Rex any way you can tell me or send me a link to help out with unblocking the ports by my ISP? This shouldn't be the issue however, as I've had the same ISP for ages, was just on Win10 before.

Comment: How can I check which ports are being used by Transmission and whether or not they are blocked.

Comment: You can run `sudo netstat -pan | fgrep transmission` to see which ports are used.

Answer (score 1):

I use qBittorrent. It's no frills fast and easy, very similar to utorrent for Windows. You can from "GNOME Software". Type qBittorrent and install, or open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
```

then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install qbittorrent
```

Once installed, you can start it from Unity Dash or application menu.

Comment: Same problem with qBittorrent. Download just sits there.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot ? @Dave

Comment: Try this here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/719345/unable-to-download-torrent-with-qbittorrent

Comment: Thanks Dave .. still no luck but looking